# Pass JavaScript array to server-side function with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to do the following steps:

1. Take a list of check box values and make them into a string array in JavaScript.
2. Take the array and send it to a server-side function.
3. Take the array server side and make it into DataTable.
4. Take the DataTable and send it as a TVP to a stored procedure.

I've gotten this to work from server-side on. Where I have trouble is going from JavaScript to server.

With my current code, I get this error:

> There are not enough fields in the Structured type. Structured types must have at least one field.

How can I pass the JavaScript array to a web method?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;


    namespace SendTVP
    {
        public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            //page variables
            string filterList = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spFilterPatientsByRace",con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                        //required for passing a table valued parameter
                        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                        param.ParameterName = "@Races";
                        //adding the DataTable
                        param.Value = dt;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }                
                }
            }
            [ScriptMethod]
            [WebMethod]
            //this method will take JS array as a parameter and turn it into a DataTable

            public void TableFilter(string filterList)
            {
                DataTable filter = new DataTable();
                filter.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Races" });
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Races" });
                foreach (string s in filterList.Split(','))
                {
                    filter.Rows.Add(s);
                }
                dt = filter;
            }
        }

}
```

If this is a complete asinine way to do it, revisions are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have two methods on your web form which require a post back cycle.

- When you call the `WebMethod`, it will create an instance of the `_default` class and set the `dt` variable, but do nothing with it.
- When you call `Button1_Click`, a new instance of the `_default` class is created, so the `dt` variable is set to `new DataTable();`. Thus, your parameter has no columns or other data.

You'll want to do your processing of the `DataTable` in one method, presumably the `TableFilter` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which is a subset of javascript, to represent the data you are passing. An example of JSON would be:

```
[ "string1", "string2" ]
```

or

```
{ "property1": "a", "property2": "b" }
```

Where the first is a valid javascript array and the second is a valid javascript object when passed directly to the browser in a `<script>` tag. [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) has various methods for dealing with JSON and you can look at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) on the .NET side for deserializing JSON into a C# object.

[Edit]

Though I should point out that it is difficult to get JSON deserialized into a C# `DataTable` because `DataTable` has a lot of properties that you would not necessarily need on the client. Your best bet would be to deserialize to a `List<T>` and iterating through that list adding to the `DataTable` rows as needed.